# HashCat on VeraCrypt non-system drive

Tags: disk-encryption, veracrypt, hashcat

With VeraCrypt, one can fully encrypt a non-system drive. I'm wondering if there's a way to run hashcat against such a drive. (Bonus points for a Windows solution.)

Answer (score 1):

The procedure should be the same as for TrueCrypt, as documented in [the hashcat FAQ](https://hashcat.net/wiki/frequently_asked_questions#how_do_i_extract_the_hashes_from_truecrypt_volumes).

You'll need to extract the first 512 bytes of the target volume, save them as a file, and use that file as the hashcat target. (Boot drives require pulling the 512 bytes starting later in the drive, but non-boot drives can be treated like file-level containers, pulling the first 512 bytes.)

On Windows, you can use [dd for windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd) to do so. Use `dd --list` to determine the drive ID for the drive, and then:

`dd if=\\.\Volume{volume-guid} of=c:\temp\veracrypt-target.img bs=512 count=1`

and:

`hashcat -a 3 -w 3 -m 137xx c:\temp\veracrypt-target.img`

(with the hashcat command modified to match your attack type).